# Stream Videos from PC to iPad?

Tags: video, ios

So I have an iPad 3 running iOS 9.2 and a PC running Windows 10. I use an app called INFUSE on my iPad to play videos and movies. Now when I was running iOS 8.4, I did something (I can't remember exactly what) on my PC, and created an ad hoc network or something like that, which allowed me to access my disk drive from infuse and play videos. After that I have upgraded iOS on my iPad (clean install). Now I can't remember how to do it again. I can create an ad hoc network but my iPad won't join it. Can someone please tell me how to replicate the process?

Comment: Try **VLC Streamer**. install **VLC streamer** on your iPad from the App Store and install **VLC Streamer Helper** on your PC. It does what you want easily.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have the [sharing permissions set for the "Everyone" profile manually on your Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/share-files-and-folders-over-the-network-from-windows-vista-inside-out) computer for the directory that holds the videos. Below is a link to the instruction on how to set this up from the Infuse website.

Makes that “SMB File Sharing is enabled on the device you wish to stream FROM"
http://support.firecore.com/hc/en-us/articles/215090977-Streaming-From-Other-Devices